# I have a problem with cookieservice in angular

Tags: angular, cookies, constructor, new-operator

Hello I have a problem with cookie service,  I want to use cookies in my project file in this way  `constructor(project_name, creator_user, public cookieService = new CookieService(document, REST_URL)) {`

I initialize the object this way (in same file) `this.lda_params = res.params; this.cookieService.set('cookie_lda', JSON.stringify(this.lda_params));`

I then create the project object in another component like this `project = new Project('', '');`
I get no compile error but the cookies are not created. I don't know what I did wrong, can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not use images to provide your code. Instead, edit your initial question and add the code directly to it.

Comment: Hello are my changes good ? Thanks for your answer